# PHP encoding Hebrew

Tags: php, encoding, hebrew

I'm writing a web app using php.
The main file (index.php) has some Hebrew chars in it and when I load it they show as "?".
The encoding for the PHP and the HTML files is UTF-8.
When I change the index.php extension to HTML, the Hebrew chars are shown well.
I tried to put this line in the code:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')
?>
```

but it didn't help.

I still want to use the file as PHP. How can I make the Hebrew chars to show?

Comment: set your encoding IDE to UTF-8! ;)

Comment: @JellyBelly: I'm using Eclipse and the encoding there is UTF-8.

Comment: You could try loading the PHP version of the page in your browser, so that it displays '?' and then cycling through some common character encodings in your browser. In Chrome, those are under the View menu. Try out ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, ISO-8859-8 etc. to see if one of them makes it look right. Then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: @Jonathan: I tried to do that, but all of the common encodings show "?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to step through:

1. Make sure the file is correctly encoded (eg with `isutf8` or similar).
2. Where is the text coming from? If it from a database, is the text stored as UTF-8? Is the connection to the database set as UTF-8 before any queries are made?
3. Make sure the header is being correctly sent (using Firebug, or Chrome developer tools, or Opera Dragonfly)
4. Check for a charset `meta` element in the head. (All of these should be set to UTF-8)
5. Make sure the browser is working properly (right-click on page, 'Page info', or similar in most browsers)

Ask if you need help with any of those.

Comment: Problem solved.
I opened the PHP file in notepad++, encoded it as "UTF 8 without BOM" and it worked.
Now, if can anyone explain what is "without BOM" it would be great.

Comment: The BOM is redundant in UTF-8 (because the multibyte UTF-8 characters have the bits of their codepoint mapped to several bytes in a very specific, non-endian way). It should not need to be used, and is mainly a legacy thing now. I can easily believe that it would cause problems to add a BOM to UTF-8 for some browsers. Well done to work it out. I guess you are using Windows, because I can't think of any other platform that would ship with a text editor adding BOMs to UTF-8 files.